# using lambda to passing arguments from another function

Tags: python, function, lambda, list-comprehension

I want to replace the values from this list `none_list = [[None, None, None]]`
 with the output from

```
def _execute():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input
```

the output should be for example `none_list = [["a","b", "c"]]`

the idea was to use `lambda` function to passing in the `output` argument inside  `map()`
to change the values

I know that the syntax of lambda is `lambda argument: expression` , 

how to use lambda in this case to passing in the argument ?

```
def _execute():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input


none_list = [[None, None, None]]


def insert_data(output):
    # take the output from _execute():
    # replace each element from none_list with each output from _execute
    global none_list
    none_list = [value for value in map(lambda output: output, none_list)]

    return none_list

while True:
    insert_data(_execute())
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what's supposed to happen exactly? `_execute` takes in an input from the user, and then how exactly is it supposed to fill the `none_list`?

Comment: Also your list has one item only, which is a list containing 3 items, is that what you have ? What about `lambda o: output` don't call the first output, because it'll make you can't use the method one

Comment: Why is `none_list` nested?

Comment: You **really** shouldn't rely on mutable global state. That is bad. In any case, there is no need for `lambda` here...  your function is ... already a function. You probably wanted something like `map(_execute, none_list)` instead of `map(lambda output: output, none_list)` which doesn't make any sense, `lambda output: output` is just a function that returns whatever you pass in to it (so pretty useless at least in this case). Note, `[value for value in <whatever>]` should just be `list(<whatever>)`